# Java Program not running in command prompt

Tags: java, compilation, command-prompt

Well, I'm able to compile my program in command prompt using

```
javac Main.java
```

It is compiling without any hassles. But the problem arises when i try to run the program. Whenever i try running it in command prompt after compiling, i get an error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: main
```

What does this mean?

And I have set my classpath and path variables too. As far as I know i seem to have covered the basics but i don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Do you have a `main()` method in you `Main` class?

Comment: Please post your command line running the `java` utility

Comment: Can you share your class ?

Comment: There could be 2 issue during run this class. First you might not using the class name properly like instead of 'Main' you might using 'main', The second issue might be classpath related .. run your class like "java -cp . Main" [here '.' is current location you may change it where your class is located].

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran - Yes. There is a main() method inside my main class.

Comment: @NaveenRamawat - I think there is some problem with the classpath only. Im not entirely sure though. Even though my classpath and path have been set under environment variables, it says that it is not sure when i try to run javac -cp

Answer (score 0):

could this be a uppercase lowercase typo? the filename and the classname as well the name when you run your program via java should all have the same name.

in your case, probably `Main` with an upper case `M`.

Comment: but Java is case-sensitive. the classname needs to match the filename.

Answer (score 0):

First,after you executed the javac ,you should check the existence of class file of main Java file

Comment: The class file is created on compilation. I feel there is some problem with the classpath and path variables. Not able to deduce it.